# Background color of my pop up window won't work

Tags: javascript

So the problem i'm having with my pop up window is that I can seem to add a background color to it. And there's no error in the debbuger.

An

```js
function creer() {
  var maFenetre;
  var tabCouleur = ["DarkGreen", "Yellow", "Red", "DeepSkyBlue", "Brown", "BurlyWood"];

  var nbFenetre = parseInt(prompt("Combien de fenêtres voulez-vous?"));


  for (var i = 0; i < nbFenetre; i++) {

    maFenetre = open("", "Page #" + i + 1, "width=500px, height=350px, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes");

    if (nbFenetre < tabCouleur.length) {
      maFenetre.document.body.style.backgroundColor = tabCouleur[i];
    } else {
      var couleurAleatoire = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
      maFenetre.document.body.style.backgroundColor = tabCouleur[couleurAleatoire];
    }
  }
}
creer();
```

Comment: The first thing which strikes the eye: `"Page #"+i+1`. It will lead to intepreting `i` and `1` as strings and string concatenation. If `i` is 7, then it will become `Page #71`, not `Page #8`. Use `"Page #"+(i+1)` to make `i+1` be calculated.

Comment: You'll want to use the DOM Inspector to check what is being applied as the background colour.

Comment: Your code is working for me in Chrome. Which browser are you using? Can you try replace colors with hex codes to see if it works for you? i.e. `#ff0000` for red

Comment: @ChrisHappy here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/tfpftnah/

Comment: @PatrickMoore [facepalm] Should have just read the code... Adding snippet.

Comment: @PatrickMoore It's actually not working for me. This function is a small piece of my code I got elements created with Document.write in my loop. But a background should be added to my pop up window but it isn't

Comment: @Kevin very possible some other JavaScript error above is causing the problem... is the pop up window opening but with white background? Or not opening at all?

Comment: @PatrickMoore opening very fine with all the elements but with white background